# Is it possible to show Google Chrome's extension icon in tray like Hangouts?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm curious is it possible to use current Google Chrome API to create an Extension that shows an icon in system tray, like Hangouts?  E.g. I would like to create mail notifier that shows number of unread emails without opening a browser.

[image: Hangouts tray icon]

Comment: @rob-w I know that question has been already asked but it was about 2 years ago and with examples to chrome dev-channel, which support has been dropped

Comment: And the answer links to a bug report that states that the feature is not supported and won't be supported (this is also re-iterated in a recent comment on the answer).

Comment: Ok so here's my question, if Hangouts can do it, why a developer can't? I see, I see. The issue is a duplicate.